# Google Drive Api V3 - how to get storage quota

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have my `$client` and now I need to get about info

`$service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client)`

I tried to do this

`$service->about->get()`

but I got this error `The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.

as the error message states the files parameter is required.

```
$optParams = array('fields' => '*');
$service->about->get($optParams);
```